# Inactive thread in a warp and memory operations

Tags: cuda

```
__device__ int arr[1]{5};

__global__ void kernel()
{
  uint32_t threadId = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

  uint32_t mask = __activemask();

  printf("id %u, mask %u, value %i\n", threadId, mask, arr[threadId]);
}

int main(int argc, char *[])
{
  kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
  gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

  return 0;
}
```

In the code above a single thread is launched. The active mask shows that indeed only one thread is active. But because of the nature of NVidia's GPUs a complete warp executes the kernel (32 threads instead of 1). I'm imagining that each thread in a warp gets assigned some thread id and based on this id a thread will access a certain part of the memory.

How does the memory operations are performed for inactive threads? Do reads and writes actually get executed? If they are that can lead to reading/writing out of bounds, like in my example, where the size of the array is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inactive threads](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture) are masked in such a way that no actual work is done.  Although it doesn't cover your case exactly an example of the handling is given [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture):

> If threads of a warp diverge via a data-dependent conditional branch, the warp executes each branch path taken, disabling threads that are not on that path.

Disabling a thread means that the thread won't do anything that is program-meaningful.

We can get some coverage for your case with the additional description [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/sourcelevel/instructioncount.htm):

> There are two reasons threads within a warp can be disabled: being inactive, and being predicated off. If the block size is not a multiple of the warp size, the last warp in the block will have inactive threads.

So the "extra threads" in a block that doesn't have a multiple of 32 threads will be inactive, also.

Inactive threads don't do anything that is meaningful to your program state; they are disabled.

You don't need to be concerned about an inactive thread making a memory request that you didn't intend.

Likewise, even if it didn't involve memory, you don't need to be concerned about an inactive thread doing any other work, such as multiplying two registers and modifying another register.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I still can not fully understand it - according to documentation, threads in a warp are executed in a **lockstep**. If a branch divergence occurs, the _inactive_ threads execute instructions anyway together with _active_ threads. At least this is what I always thought happens in a GPU. But now you state that the _inactive_ threads are **disabled**. If I understand it correctly that means they don't do any work at all. But that would mean there is no **lockstep** for these threads.

Comment: I acknowledge that when we use words like "lockstep", they are useful for description and cover a great many cases, good for general understanding.  But if you then decide that because the word lockstep was used, that it *always* applies, and it *always* means precisely identical behavior across a warp, independent of any other aspect of GPU functionality, then you will admittedly have difficulty reconciling these concepts. If lockstep applied that way, there would be no need for an active mask.  But the GPU whitepapers clearly indicate that the active mask is part of the HW warp mechanism

Comment: I experienced (on Turing) that predicated off threads could lead to slower memory accesses, if the addresses of the not executing threads were not optimal (I do not remember, whether it was shared or global memory - I believe shared memory).